# create a Map from int array with index as key and value as array element in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

this is a integer array I have

[9,3,15,20,7]

I want to create a map like

0->9
1->3

with index as key and array element as value

IntStream.range(0,postorder.length).collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> postorder[i],i->i));

I tried like this but getting compilation error as required type int found object
is there any to create map like this using streams in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IntStream.range(0, postorder.length)
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> postorder[i], (a, b) -> b));
```

Comment: this worked can you explain about this I can't understand the (a, b) -> b) part

Comment: In your case, you can remove `(a, b) -> b`  part, `.collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> postorder[i]);` will works as well. 

`(a, b) -> b)` is a merge function, it will be used if there is duplicate key of map. In your case it can be ignored.

You can see the api doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Answer (score 2):

You should have `boxed()` the IntStream

```
final int[] postorder = {2,5, 6, 8};
Map<Object, Object> map = IntStream
        .range(0,postorder.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(index -> index, index-> postorder[index]));
System.out.println(map);
```